# How to corporate condition statements in get;set properties for date time in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, get, set

i was playing around with classes and date time. i want to check a person's age if they're over 16 or not using get,set property. here is the class `Test`

```
class Test
    {
        private DateTime _Dob;
        public DateTime Dob
        {
            get { return _Dob; }
            set
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Year - 16 < _Dob.Year)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error");
                }
                else
                {
                _Dob = value; }
            }
        }
        public Test(DateTime dob)
        {
            _Dob = dob;
        }
```

and here is main

```
Test dob = new Test(new DateTime(2007,12,01));
            dob.Dob();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

it said in main `dob.Dob();` is not a method. how can i fix this?

Comment: Note that this is not a good practice. Such a check on a getter is unexpected behaviour. If I get an error on a getter, I assume that _getting the value_ went wrong. This kind of validation you normally expect on a _setter_ or in this case, on the _constructor_ of your class. Not sure if it matters, by the way, but your check is not checking "if they're over 16 or not". If I was born in December 2002, I pass the check, even though I'm only 15.

Comment: Sorry, you _are_ using the setter, which is correct. The fact that it doesn't work is because you are not using the setter.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things going on here and many schools of thought.

1. If you need to do validation, its good practice not to do this in a property setter. There are some good reasons why you don't want to do any heavy lifting inside a setter as follows

   - Because properties "appear" to be fields, it is not always apparent that they can throw a (by-design) exception; whereas with methods, programmers are trained to expect and investigate whether exceptions are an expected consequence of invoking the method.
   - Getters are used by a lot of .NET infrastructure, like serializers and databinding (in WinForms and WPF for example) - dealing with exceptions in such contexts can rapidly become problematic.
   - Property getters are automatically evaluated by debuggers when you watch or inspect an object. An exception here can be confusing and slow down your debugging efforts. It's also undesirable to perform other expensive operations in properties (like accessing a database) for the same reasons.
   - Properties are often used in a chaining convention: `obj.PropA.AnotherProp.YetAnother` - with this kind of syntax it becomes problematic to decide where to inject exception catch statements.
2. If you are going to validate, its probably worth while throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, if you do this, then this is better to be in a method and setting your property to a `private` set, so dirty little fingers don't skip the validation

So my OCD modified your class [**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RORBJA)

```
public class Test
{
    // make it a private setter so people don't try to set the property
    // without validation
    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    // validation is probably best done outside of a property
    public void SetDateOfBirth(DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        if (dateOfBirth.Year > DateTime.Now.Year - 16)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dateOfBirth", "Date of birth year cannot be after : " + (DateTime.Now.Year - 16));
        }

        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Test()
    {
    }

    // if you really want one stage construction,
    // lets call the common DoB validation
    public Test(DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        SetDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
    }
}
```

**Example usage**

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Testing invalid constrcutor");
    var test = new Test(new DateTime(2007, 12, 01));
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

---

**Further reading**

[Property Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property)

Comment: Excellent answer, and a great example of giving the client what they need instead of what they want.

Comment: Your first point is confused IMO - it says that you shouldn't do validation in a *setter*, but then talks about various situations in which a *getter* is called. I think it's fine to validate in a setter, and indeed it's pretty common to do so. I disagree with using a separate method though - that makes it really easy to accidentally set the value without validation within the class.

Comment: @DaisyShipton as i said there a various schools of thought, and no one solution fits all, however i did provide as much information as i could.

Comment: @TheGeneral: But even if I agreed that validation shouldn't be done in a property setter (and again, I don't; try setting a `List<T>.Capacity` to -1 for example), I'd want to see different arguments. 3 of your 4 bullet points are about when *getters* are called. Those bullet points just don't support your point about when setters are called. I think the answer would at least be better with those bullet points removed.

Comment: @DaisyShipton yes in many places the framework validates in a property, however you are missing the point, and worrying about it too much. I think its a good rule of thumb (a guideline) and as such (as always) it should be up to the who ever is writing the code and who is reviewing it. However i would have felt dirty throwing in this situation for this users question, just as i would writing to the console from the property and note setting anything.

Comment: @TheGeneral: As I say, we can agree to disagree on whether it's a good idea (although I think it would make sense to make it clearer that your claim of "its good practice not to do this in a property setter" is one of the aspects where there are many schools of thought) , but you've consistently ignored my point that of your "good reasons" only the first one is relevant.

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 2):

To address the reason your code isn't compiling: you're calling `Dob` as if it's a method. It isn't; it's a property. Your property has a getter and a setter; they're executed in these cases:

```
 Test test = new Test(new DateTime(...));
 DateTime fetched = test.Dob;  // Executes the getter
 test.Dob = new DateTime(...); // Executes the setter
```

So that's the aspect about your code not compiling.

Once that's fixed (e.g. by using `DateTime dateOfBirth = test.Dob;` you still won't be validating anything, because of this code:

```
public Test(DateTime dob)
{
    _Dob = dob;
}
```

That's assigning directly to the field; it's not using the setter - you're bypassing all your validation.

Next, your validation is using `_Dob.Year` instead of `value`, which means it's validating that the *previously set* property value is correct.

Next, the validation itself is incorrect in that it's not just checking the year part without any respect for months and days. If my date of birth were April 22nd 2002 (I wish!), then yesterday I would not have been 16 years old, but today I would be... your code wouldn't spot the difference. In the code below, I've assumed that your "over 16" constraint is actually "at least 16 years old".

Finally, printing an error message in the console is not the idiomatic way of reporting an error. Use exceptions to report errors. (There are cases where you want to perform validation separately on multiple items and collect all the invalid aspects, but that's beyond the scope of this question.)

Personally I think it's fine to validate within a property setter, assuming you need it to be available at all - an alternative design would be to make the `Dob` property read-only, and validate on construction instead. That would side-step the whole discussion about whether or not a property setter should throw. However, assuming you *do* want a property setter, here's complete code that does what you probably expected:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    private DateTime dateOfBirth;

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get => dateOfBirth;
        set
        {
            // Alternative: if (DateTime.Now.AddYears(-16) > value)
            // They behave differently around leap years. Note that
            // currently this is sensitive to the system time zone
            // and the system clock.
            if (value.AddYears(16).Date > DateTime.Today)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    nameof(value), "User must be at least 16 years old");
            }
            dateOfBirth = value;
        }
    }

    public Test(DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Note: executed on April 22nd 2018
        Test test = new Test(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(test.DateOfBirth);
        test.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2002, 4, 22); // Fine: 16th birthday
        Console.WriteLine(test.DateOfBirth);
        test.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2002, 4, 23);
    }
}
```

One final note: using the system clock (and system time zone) directly makes your code hard to test. I like treating the clock as a dependency, with an interface (e.g. `IClock`) with a system clock implementation and a fake clock implementation. You'd then want to work out which time zone you're interested in, as that can affect the user's age. (I could be 16 in New York but not in Los Angeles, for example.) Those are fairly separate issues though.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using get; set; you don't want to call Dob as a function but just like you would access a normal property of the class.

```
Test dob = new Test(new DateTime(2007,12,01));
var myDob = dob.Dob;
// myDob is what is return from the get in your get function
```

Comment: thanks, your solution doesn't cause any syntax nor  logic error, however it returns blanks. some how it skipped the conditions

Comment: @EddieVu: Yes, because your constructor assigns directly to the field, and then the second line of code here calls the getter. Nothing is calling the setter.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using your setter.

Use it in your constructor like this:

```
public Test(DateTime dob)
{
    this.Dob = dob;
}
```

Or call the setter from the outside:

```
dob.Dob = new DateTime(2007,12,01);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dob` is a *property* of class `Test`, not a method.

You can access `Dob` like:

```
var test = new Test(new DateTime(2010, 01, 01));
var dob = test.Dob;
```

However, you've noticed that your `set` logic didn't kick in when you called the `Test` constructor. I believe this is because your age check is incorrect. The reason your `set` logic isn't performing the check appropriately when you call the constructor is because you're comparing `_Dob.Year` before it has a value. You want to use the `value` keyword to get the value that was attempted to be set.

See the example below (with the fixed age check):

```
public DateTime Dob
{
    get
    {
        return _Dob;
    }
    set
    {
        if (GetAge(value) < 16)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You ain't 16!");
        }
        else
        {
            _Dob = value;
        }
    }
}

private int GetAge(DateTime dob)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    int age = today.Year - dob.Year;
    if (dob > today.AddYears(-age))
        age--;

   return age;
}
```